# Owner-draw ListBox using Compact Framework

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, listbox

I want to subclass the ListBox control and set the `LBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE‎` style.  Subclassing is no problem and I can get messages through my own WndProc.  (Actually I subclass the ListBox's parent in this case, as it is what is supposed to receive the `WM_MEASUREITEM` and `WM_DRAWITEM` messages).  The problem is that I never get `WM_MEASUREITEM` or `WM_DRAWITEM` messages and the control continues to paint itself.

Both styles should be supported in WM5.0 and up:
  WinCE3.0 supports neither: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms959988.aspx
  WinCE5.0 supports both: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453299.aspx

Even `LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` would be a start, but I can't get either to work.

My best guess is that the `LBS_OWNERDRAWx` style needs to be set at `CreateWindowEx()` time, as `SetWindowLong()` doesn't seem to change it.  If that's the case, CF doesn't expose any methods that let me override window creation, and also doesn't expose anything like CreateParams (in full framework) or PreCreateWindow() that allows modifying the window-style before creation.  (They're all there in the `Control` class but they're `internal`, so not accessible).

Has anyone managed to successfully do owner-drawing (even FIXED) **using the actual Windows ListBox control** on CF?  Alternately, has anyone figured out a way to override the window-styles passed to CreateWindowEx() in a Control-based control? If so, please share your secrets :-)

Note: I do not want to create a list control from scratch; I can do that and there are various good examples of that out there, but that's not what this question is about.

CF2.0; WM6.1.